# How to capture codeigniter Duplicate entry query error

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, race-condition

A race condition occurs with inserting data to a table in MySQL. I check that there are no duplicate keys but sometimes there is another PHP thread doing the same thing:

```
DEBUG - 2018-02-03 03:40:41 --> [9GH212VT] SELECT * FROM `device_cache` WHERE `md5sum` = '4fd43e58b0a538a0d97e4b8074b0aa80'; - 7.2002410888672E-5
DEBUG - 2018-02-03 03:40:41 --> [DLZ6FPAE] INSERT INTO `device_cache` (`md5sum`, `user_agent`, `data`) VALUES ('4fd43e58b0a538a0d97e4b8074b0aa80', '...'); - 0.10529589653015
ERROR - 2018-02-03 03:40:41 --> [QCSUMNJ5] Query error: Duplicate entry '4fd43e58b0a538a0d97e4b8074b0aa80' for key 'PRIMARY' - Invalid query: INSERT INTO `device_cache` (`md5sum`, `user_agent`, `data`) VALUES ('4fd43e58b0a538a0d97e4b8074b0aa80', '...')
```

I want to know if I can catch this error, Codeigniter terminates execution when it found this error.

Comment: If you performing a select on the key and it returns a result then perform an update, else perform an insert.

Comment: Have you tried [handling errors](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors) or [transactions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw if it exist there is no need to insert it, however there is a race condition where a row is inserted (by other process) after the select used to check if it exists and before the insert.

Comment: Then other process need to use transactions with [lock](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) query.

Answer (score 0):

In application/config/database.php set

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

and Codeigniter won't stop execution